# How to use componentWillMount in React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to convert a HOC - class-based component into functional component. This component is using for showing error modal . Here is the class-based component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Modal from '../../components/UI/Modal/Modal';
import Aux from '../Aux/Aux';

const withErrorHandler = ( WrappedComponent, axios ) => {
  return class extends Component {
    state = {
      error: null
    }

    componentWillMount () {
      this.reqInterceptor = axios.interceptors.request.use( req => {
        this.setState( { error: null } );
        return req;
      });
      this.resInterceptor = axios.interceptors.response.use( res => res, error => {
        this.setState( { error: error } );
      });
    }

    componentWillUnmount () {
      axios.interceptors.request.eject( this.reqInterceptor );
      axios.interceptors.response.eject( this.resInterceptor );
    }

    errorConfirmedHandler = () => {
      this.setState( { error: null } );
    }

    render () {
      return (
        <Aux>
           <Modal
             show={this.state.error}
             modalClosed={this.errorConfirmedHandler}>
             {this.state.error ? this.state.error.message : null}
           </Modal>
           <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
        </Aux>
      );
     }
   }
 }

 export default withErrorHandler;
```

Here is my functional component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

import Modal from '../../components/UI/Modal/Modal';
import Aux from '../Auxilirary/Auxiliary';

const withErrorHandler = (WrappedComponent, axios) => {
  return props => {
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);

    const reqInterceptor = axios.interceptors.request.use(req => {
      setError(null);
      return req;
    }); //Not working
    const resInterceptor = axios.interceptors.response.use(
      res => res,
      err => {
        setError(err);
      }
    ); //Not working
    
    useEffect(() => {  
      return () => { //eject when unmount
        axios.interceptors.request.eject(reqInterceptor);
        axios.interceptors.response.eject(resInterceptor);
      };
    }, [reqInterceptor, resInterceptor]);

    const errorConfirmedHandler = () => {
      setError(null);
    };

       return (
        <Aux>
          <Modal show={error} modalClosed={errorConfirmedHandler}> // return null
            {error ? error.message : null}
          </Modal>
          <WrappedComponent {...props} />
        </Aux>
       );
    };
  };

 export default withErrorHandler;
```

But the catch error function not working. Is there anyway that I can add the logic function before rendering ?

Comment: Why do you add your interceptors to dependencies array to `useEffect` ? I think you should remove from the array and dependencies array should be empty.

Comment: The idea is when the interceptors changed. It will eject the old one and create new one after that.

Answer (score 0):

A wild guess from the code above that this part

```
   const resInterceptor = axios.interceptors.response.use(
  res => res,
  err => {
    setError(err);
  }
); //Not working
```

will run only at the initialization of the component, so if no error at the first initialization it will return null and keep it without changes.

What I see that you have to set the error inside the useEffect because it's the hook that's called each time a re-render happen, this you make sure that this bulk of code will be executed each time you re-render this component

```
     useEffect(() => {
    //your old code ..
    const reqInterceptor = axios.interceptors.request.use((req) => {
      setError(null);
      return req;
    });
    const resInterceptor = axios.interceptors.response.use(
      (res) => res,
      (err) => {
        setError(err);
      },
    );
    reqInterceptor();
    resInterceptor();
  });
```

Comment: reqInterceptor and resInterceptor  can't be called as a function. And if I set reqInterceptor 
 and resInterceptor inside useEffect, I can't eject them becasuee they're not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Remove <React.StrictMode> in App.js component, problem solved !!!